# Autowiring session in Spring?

Tags: spring, session, autowired

I'm new to spring and I've written a method that uses the HttpSession object. I use the method qite often. Right now I pass the parameter as a argument to the method. But that means that everywhere I use the method, I need to pass it in as a parameter, which means the method calling it needs the parameter HttpSession as parameter. I was wondering if I could somehow pass the session automatically (@Autowire?) so I dont need to pass it every time I use the method:

As an example:

```
public User getUser(HttpSession session){
   //DoStuff
}
```

Everywhere I call the method I need to pass in the session:

```
public void addItem(@RequestParam(value="id") int id, HttpSession session){
        super.getUser(session);
       //doStuff
}
```

I don't want the HttpSession session in the signature, whenever I have to call getUser(...), Is there a way to let Spring fill in this session in getUser(), automatically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using:

```
@Autowired 
private HttpSession httpSession;
```

Comment: Great, thank you, I'm feeling so stupid right now :s