# Field httpSession in required a bean of type 'javax.servlet.http.HttpSession' that could not be found

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, servlets, httpsession

I'm getting this error

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field httpSession in com.example.splitwise.Controllers.UserController required a bean of type 'javax.servlet.http.HttpSession' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'javax.servlet.http.HttpSession' in your configuration.


Process finished with exit code 0


###############################################################################
```

This is my controller class

```java
package com.example.splitwise.Controllers;

import com.example.splitwise.DTOS.RequestDTO;
import com.example.splitwise.DTOS.ResponseDTO;
import com.example.splitwise.Modals.Users;
import com.example.splitwise.Services.UserServices;
import jakarta.validation.Valid;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class UserController {

    private UserServices userServices;

    @Autowired
    private HttpSession httpSession;

    private UserController(UserServices userServices) {
        this.userServices = userServices;
    }

    @PostMapping("/signup")
    public ResponseEntity<ResponseDTO> signup(@RequestBody RequestDTO requestDTO) {
        ResponseDTO responseDTO = new ResponseDTO();

        // Check if the user already exists
//        Users existingUser = userServices.findBy(requestDTO.getUserEmail());
//        if (existingUser != null) {
//            responseDTO.setMessage("User already exists");
//            responseDTO.setStatus("Failure");
//            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).body(responseDTO);
//        }

        // Create the new user
        Users user = userServices.signup(requestDTO);
        if (user != null) {
            responseDTO.setMessage("Signup is Successful");
            responseDTO.setStatus("Success");
        } else {
            responseDTO.setMessage("Failure in Signup: ");
            responseDTO.setStatus("Failure");
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body(responseDTO);
        }

        return ResponseEntity.ok(responseDTO);
    }

    @GetMapping("/login")
    public ResponseEntity<ResponseDTO> login(@Valid @RequestBody RequestDTO requestDTO, @RequestParam HttpServletRequest request) {
        ResponseDTO responseDTO = new ResponseDTO();

        // Check if the user is already logged in
        Users currentUser = (Users) request.getSession().getAttribute("users");
        if (currentUser != null) {
            responseDTO.setMessage("User already logged in");
            responseDTO.setStatus("Failure");
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).body(responseDTO);
        }

        // Login the user
        Users user = userServices.login(requestDTO.getUserEmail(), requestDTO.getUserPassword());
        if (user != null) {
            request.getSession().setAttribute("users", user);
            responseDTO.setMessage("is logged in");
            responseDTO.setStatus("Success");
        } else {
            responseDTO.setMessage("Failure in Login: ");
            responseDTO.setStatus("Failure");
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body(responseDTO);
        }

        return ResponseEntity.ok(responseDTO);
    }

}
```

pom.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>splitwise</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>splitwise</name>
    <description>backend for splitwise</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>-->``
<!--        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
<!--            <scope>provided</scope>-->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-session-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-session-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

config

```ini
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/xxxx
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=xxxx
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

spring.session.store-type=jdbc
spring.session.jdbc.initialize-schema=always
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was not aware that you can autowire `HttpSession`, but according to [Autowiring session in Spring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29487885/autowiring-session-in-spring) it is possible (I guess Spring uses a proxy and accesses the current session somehow).

The problem is that you imported `javax.servlet.HttpSession`, but you're using Spring Boot 3.1, and since Spring Boot 3, you need to use `jakarta.servlet.HttpSession`. So, change the import, and make sure that you remove dependencies that import the old `javax.*` classes. For example, remove the dependency on `javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:4.0.1` from your POM, Spring Boot 3 and higher don't use it, and other dependencies or your code that use classes from this library won't actual work under Spring Boot 3.